# Exception in iPhone app : Modal transition is already in progress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have what I believe is a fairly simple application at the moment based on a few tutorials cobbled together.  I'm using XCode 3.2.3 in OSX 10.6.4.  It started as a standard iPhone "Window Based Application".  Using interface builder I have added a Tab Bar Controller using the O'Reilly video tutorial here:

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/06/tab-bars-and-navigation-bars-t.html

In the first Tab I have a standard UIView with two buttons.  Both call the same function to display a UIImagePickerController:

```
-(IBAction) btnPhotoClicked:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
if((UIButton *)sender == btnChoosePhoto)
{
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
}
```

I am running the code inside an emulator so only ever click the button called Choose Photo.  When the dialogue is released with a photo chosen this function runs:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary  *)info {
NSURL *mediaUrl;

mediaUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

if (mediaUrl == nil)
{
    imagePuzzle = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(imagePuzzle == nil)
    {
        //--- Original Image was selected ---
        imagePuzzle = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    else {
        //--- Get the edited image ---
        //--- If it was successful the above valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
        //--- would have assigned it already.
    }
}
else {
    //--- Muppet selected a video
}

// Animate the picker window going away
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
ImageViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
imageViewController.delegate = self;    
[self presentModalViewController:imageViewController animated:YES];
[imageViewController release];
}
```

This is where my problem lies.  I've tried many different hacks and iterations but the above code is the simplest to present the problem.  When the imageViewController is displayed as a modal dialogue the following exception is thrown:

```
2010-07-09 15:29:29.667 Golovomka[15183:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal
transition from <NewViewController: 0x5915f80> to <ImageViewController: 0x594a350>     
while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear
to know the current transition has completed'
```

How do I cure this?  I have tried delays and other tricks but do not really understand how I'm supposed to use viewDidAppear or viewDidDisappear to help me.  Also of note is that a very basic application with one view loading the picker then displaying another view with the image in does not produce the error.  Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To address the specific issue described here, you could add the viewDidAppear method in your class:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (/*just visited ImagePicker*/)
    {
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = [[ImageViewController alloc] init];
        imageViewController.delegate = self;    
        [self presentModalViewController:imageViewController animated:YES];
        [imageViewController release];
    }
}
```

Remove those lines from below your call:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So, whenever your class `self` appears (is displayed), it will call `viewDidAppear`...  Since this most likely isn't *really* what you want all the time, you could add some variables to set/clear that defines whether or not to immediately present the `imageViewController` when `self` is displayed.  Something like "If coming from image picker, show the imageViewController, otherwise do nothing".

That said, imho, pushing modal views is should generally be done in response to a user action and I would maybe rethink the user experience here - e.g. add a subview instead of pushing a modal view which you could do where your currently have the code - but if you're just playing around with some tutorials that should solve the NSInternalInconsistencyException. :)  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try that in my code as it's neater than what I am doing.  I'm pushing the modal view after the user has taken a picture or selected a photo.  The idea here is that there is some potentially intense image processing and I want to display that modally to the user until it completes.  So there is user action involved before forcing the modal view.

As an aside I eventually killed the exception with this:
<blockquote>
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
</blockquote>

Comment: OK picker.view.superview removeFromSuperview.  Really really bad solution unless you like blank screens for everything afterwards!  I rebuilt the app from scratch in the end using a nav bar controller within a tab bar app and that worked fine.  On another note, your solution also worked.  Thank you.  Much much clearer now.  I've only been doing this for 2 days from a C/C++/Java/Perl/bash background.

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 5.0 and above you can use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  //present another modal view controller here
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue quite a few times. I recently started using this simple fix:

When I am going to present a new modal view controller immediately after dismissing another modal view controller, I simply dismiss the first one with argument NO in `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

Since the second view is presented with an animation, you hardly notice that the first one goes away fast. And you never get the transitions conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when i wanted to present an MFMailComposeViewController immediately after dismissing the UIImagePickerController. Heres what i did:

1. I removed the `[imagePicker release];` statement from where i was presenting the image picker and put it in didFinishPickingMedia callback.
2. I used `[self performSelector:@selector(presentMailComposer:) withObject:image afterDelay:1.0f];`

Here's my code:
Displaying Image Picker

`if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];`

```
    if ([media containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage] == YES) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        //[picker release];
    }

}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unavailable!"
                                                    message:@"Could not open the Photo Library."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Image Picker Delegate Callback - didFinishPickingMedia

`NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];`

```
if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *photoTaken = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    //Save Photo to library only if it wasnt already saved i.e. its just been taken
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoTaken, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

    //Pull up MFMailComposeView Controller
    [self performSelector:@selector(composeMailWithPhoto:) withObject:photoTaken afterDelay:1.0f];
}

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Display Mail Composer View

`if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {`

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailPicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailPicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // Fill out the email fields and Attach photograph to mail
    static NSString *imageType = @"image/jpeg";
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithString:@"MyCoffeeCup.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    [mailPicker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:imageType fileName:imageName];
    [mailPicker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"hello@xische.com"]];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:mailPicker animated:YES];
    [mailPicker release];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unavailable!"
                                                    message:@"This device cannot send emails."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```